# Как можно выделить "общую" память в RAM для нескольких программ и подключаемых устройств

Tags: java, c++, память, usb, ram

Суть такая, 2 программы должны общаться между собой, в добавок с ним общается устройство через USB, нужно сделать память общую для них, как такое можно реализовать, и как с этим работать?
Платформа Linux, Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shared Memory. В Linux для этого просто отображается один файл из /dev/shm в память обеими программами.

Answer (score 1):

Вот готовая кроссплатформленная либа для Shared Memory: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html